# error in reading file in

Tags: c

i am trying to data (given below ) of a text file but i keep getting the error too few arguments

```
1/1/1990/0/0 774.359070
1/1/1990/0/10 772.973206
1/1/1990/0/20 739.628784
1/1/1990/0/30 680.130066
1/1/1990/0/40 618.887695
```

my code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* input;
    FILE* output;

    input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    output = fopen(argv[2],"w");

    float date;
    float value;

    while(fscanf(input,"%f/%f/%f/%f/%f/%f\n",&date, &value)!= EOF)
    {


    }
    fprintf(output,"%f\n/%f\n/%f\n/%f\n/%f\n/%f\n",date, value);

    return 0;
}
```

this is the error i get

```
float_search.c: In function 'main':
float_search.c:15:2: warning: too few arguments for format
float_search.c:20:2: warning: too few arguments for format
```

what am i doing wrong??

// UPDATED CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* input;
    FILE* output;

    input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    output = fopen(argv[2],"w");

    int date1,date2,date3,date4,date5;
    float value;

    while(fscanf(input,"%d/%d/%d/%d/%d/%f\n",&date1,&date2,&date3,&date4,&date5, &value)!= EOF)
    {

        fprintf(output,"%d\n/%d\n/%d\n/%d\n/%d\n/%f\n",date1,date2,date3,date4,date5,value);
    }
    fprintf(output,"%d\n/%d\n/%d\n/%d\n/%d\n/%f\n",date1,date2,date3,date4,date5,value);

    return 0;
}
```

above is the updated code with the changes, when prinitng it out i get the following output

```
46804
/4196128
/32765
/-1590701960
/0
/0.000000
34501
```

03

Answer (score 4):

You have six format specifiers (`%f`) but are only giving it two places to put them. Make more variables. Additionally, you probably only want floats for the last field; the rest should be integers.

---

With your updated code, the reason your output is not identical to the input is all of the `\n`s. Each `\n` adds a new line, and you only want one at the end. Remove all but the last one.

Comment: i am sorry but from two place do you mean argv[1]?

Comment: i think i get it , you mean the data variables?

Comment: @Jordan yes, each format specifier (for example the `%f` you wrote) needs an input argument (like `&date`). Your compiler is checking for that and warns you if the amount of parameters does not match the amount of format specifiers.

Comment: May be beneficial to wrap your date values into a single struct for clarity and set each value rather than separate variables.

Comment: what i am trying to do is to print out the exact same values but i am getting it wrong. ill post my updated code in a min. If you could tell me where i am wrong now since i made the changes

Comment: @Jordan Just be sure that your updates to the question don't change the overall theme of the original. It may be necessary to create a new one.

Comment: i hope i did it rite, i am still new to this

Comment: @Jordan: The reason it's split up when you output it is because you have a `\n` after every thing you output. You probably only want an `\n` at the end of the line. Remove every `\n` except the last one.

Comment: @why is my question gettin down voted? mayb i am not smart as people here, but atlest i am trying .

Comment: @Jordan Excuse some members here. They often do drive-by downvoting without leaving explanations or feel the question is simple to them.

Answer (score 0):

You have put format for 6 floats and output parameters for only two.
you can try this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE* input;
    FILE* output;

    input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    output = fopen(argv[2],"w");

    int date[5];
    float value;

    while(fscanf(input,"%d/%d/%d/%d/%d %f\n",&date[0],&date[1],&date[2],&date[3],&date[4], &value)!= EOF)
    {


    }
    fprintf(output,"%d\n/%d\n/%d\n/%d\n/%d\n/%f\n",date[0],date[1],date[2],date[3],date[4], value);

    return 0;
}
```